# Remove commas from a string using js

Tags: javascript

I have a Address like

```
 Address : 273A-84, Sundharam Street,, Ganthi Path, Kovai,,,,India,641001
```

If string has more than 2 commas i want to replace with single comma.

In above address next to street and next to kovai there is multiple commas.I want to replace with single comma.

My expected output is:

```
Address : 273A-84, Sundharam Street,Ganthi Path,Kovai,India,641001
```

Please suggest regular expression.

Comment: `replace(/,,*/g,',')`

Comment: @Baskar I added answer for you question, could you give feedback, problem solved or not ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Address : **273A-84, Sundharam Street,, Ganthi Path, Kovai,,,,India,641001**";

str.replace(/\,{1,}/gi, ',');
```

DEMO:[http://jsbin.com/sejuma/2/](http://jsbin.com/sejuma/2/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
 var str="Address : 273A-84, Sundharam Street,, Ganthi Path, Kovai,,,,India,641001 ";
    res = str.replace(/^[, ]+|[, ]+$|[, ]+/g, ",").trim();
    alert("{" + res+ "}");
```